# Magento 2 - integrating Tawk.to chat issue

Tags: magento2, extensions

I'm trying to integrate Tawk.to chat widget into my Magento 2 site hosted on a shared server environment. And I downloaded the extension files following the guidelines given here: `https://www.tawk.to/knowledgebase/plugins-and-modules/magento-2-integration/`. After extracting and copying the files to the root directory of my website, I requested my web host to run the needed command lines. After that my site went blank, and I got back to the hosting provider. The web host informed me that, in their own words, "The installation is being halted as it's asking for a `http://repo.magento.com` username and password." I then provided them with my Magento.com username and password, but yet, nothing has been done by them.

My web host finally sent the following error message that was generated during the aborted:

```
=============
[root@sixteen ~]# cd /home/hosting_username/public_html
[root@sixteen public_html]# php composer.phar require tawk/widget

Authentication required (repo.magento.com):
  Username: my_magento.com_email_address
  Password: my_magento.com_password

[Composer\Downloader\TransportException]
Invalid credentials for 'https://repo.magento.com/packages.json', aborting.

require [--dev] [--prefer-source] [--prefer-dist] [--no-progress] [--no-suggest] [--no-update] [--no-scripts] [--update-no-dev] [--update-with-dependencies] [--ignore-platform-reqs] [--prefer-stable] [--prefer-lowest] [--sort-packages] [-o|--optimize-autoloader] [-a|--classmap-authoritative] [--apcu-autoloader] [--] [<packages>]...

[root@sixteen public_html]#

==================
```

Does anyone know why this happened and what is the fix?

Any insight would be much appreciated, as always. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Go to root directory of your store and run below commands step by step.

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
php bin/magento cache:flush
chmod -R 777 var pub
```

Make sure there is no .maintenance.flag file under var folder.
if found than remove it.

Thanks

Comment: thanks for your input. Does it mean that the command, 'php bin/magento module:enable Tawk_Widget', to enable Tawk.to is unnecessary? And what exactly does  'chmod -R 777 var pub' do?

Comment: Hi, php bin/magento module:enable Tawk_Widget command enable extension. chmod -R 777 var pub will change folder permission to 777.

Comment: Oh thanks. I will update this post later with Composer error message